# Auto mount partition with read/write permissons

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount

I have a hard drive (Formatted with NTFS) that I need to auto mount in fstab.

I basically want this to be like my home directory, so I (And other programs) should be be able to write to it, read files, create directorys and so on.

Here is what I currently have in my fstab:

```
UUID=7099E21207CE11EC                           /mnt/v      auto            umask=022,dmask=022,uid=1000,gid=985 0 0
```

I went through a lot of iterations with that and I don't remember what exactly I tried, but the furthest I got was being able to read from it.

I'm using arch btw, my user id is 1000 and I have a group called users which has the id 985, although I tried setting the gid to 1000 as well.

Sorry if this is a noob question but I don't really understand file permissions and ownerships and really need this to work.

Comment: You have to use the "rw" option in the 4th field . See [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) and [fstab(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) . Your entry should look like the second entry of [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/x19-3.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.z3AezuDhOm.png). I don't think it's necessary but you have to change the "0 0 " to "0 2" for example at the end of the file . You said you could mount it , so I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi When I put `UUID=7099E21207CE11EC                           /mnt/Vault      auto            uid=1000,gid=985,rw,relatime    0 0` it mounts and I can read but I can't write.

Comment: Have you created and used that partition in windows and btw shut down the windows ( I mean not soft reboot) before booting into linux ? What do you get when you run "sudo mount UUID=7099E21207CE11EC /mnt/Vault -o uid=1000,gid=985,rw,relatime " ? I think it might be a problem with windows NTFS drive's metadata that hasn't gotten flushed yet so your linux OS hasn't the necessary bits of information to mount the filesystem as RW.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I might have created the partition in windows, but I have used it without a problem for more than a month on linux (Never even booted windows). I have now switched distros (Debian based -> Arch),  could that have to do anything with it?
The command doesn't output anything.

Comment: So if the mount command doesn't output anything it should have mounted it correctly. But if still you're not able to write into it , try rebooting to your windows and then reboot back into linux (soft , not hard reboot ) to see if it gets solved. And my recommendation is that if you don't want to use that partition (easily) in windows  , you can reformat it to ext4 or some more-linux-compatible filesystem type rather than NTFS. It's quite difficult to work with NTFS in linux (e.g resizing)  because of the proprietary nature of NTFS.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I don't have windows installed anymore, I might try a few more things, if nothing works I will reformat to ext4. Thanks anyways for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @parsa-mousavi pointed out you definitely have to add the "rw" option to the 4th field:

```
UUID=7099E21207CE11EC  /mnt/v  auto  rw,umask=022,dmask=022,uid=1000,gid=985 0 0
```

BTW: You can often see "defaults" instead here which among other things means "rw".

That's the obvious thing but there might be other pitfalls:

- Verify that the file system is mounted with the correct file system type by checking the output of `mount | grep '/mnt/v'`. You want to see "ntfs-3g" here. I haven't used NTFS since years but in the old days the "ntfs" driver had limited capabilities - it only allowed read access - whereas the 3rd generation NTFS driver also supported save write access.
- If the filesystem hasn't been unmounted cleanly Linux drivers might have problems (again limitations). When you boot Windows it will repair these issues (this usually happens automatically during system start). Make sure you shut Windows down cleanly before trying again in Linux.
- Try dropping the `umask`, `dmask`, `uid`, and `gid` parameters. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) says:

  > By default, files and directories are owned by the effective user and group of the mounting process, and everybody has full read, write, execution and directory browsing permissions. You can also assign permissions to a single user by using the uid and/or the gid options together with the umask, or fmask and dmask options.

Comment: It was a driver issue. I'm not sure if that driver wasn't installed by default or if the auto option didn't select it, anyways I installed `ntfs-3g-fuse` from the aur and changed the `auto` to `ntfs-3g` and now it works perfectly!